# It is normal for Meteorite to never finish?

Tags: video

I'm using Meteorite to repair a `mkv` file and whilst it does appear to create a repaired copy, the program just hangs with the progress bar not quite complete...

[image]

according to task manager, it is doing something but I can leave it like this for quite a while and nothing changes.  What should it do at the end, once it is complete?

Comment: Maybe you can try with `ffmpeg` to repair file?

Comment: This isn't a software recommendation, it's a product support issue, best addressed by the developers.